# javascript: get month/year/day from unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I have a unix timestamp, e.g., 1313564400000.00. How do I convert it into Date object and get month/year/day accordingly? The following won't work:

```
function getdhm(timestamp) {
        var date = Date.parse(timestamp);
        var month = date.getMonth();
        var day = date.getDay();
        var year = date.getYear();

        var formattedTime = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
        return formattedTime;

    }
```

Comment: Date.getYear has been deprecated in favor of Date.getFullYear, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
var date = new Date(1313564400000);
var month = date.getMonth();
```

etc.

This will be in the user's browser's local time.

Comment: WARNING: This will not work in all cases. For example, 1477958400000 is Oct 1st, 2016. But new Date(1477958400000).getDate() will give you 31! (depending on your local timezone)

Comment: I can confirm what @mindeavor said. For getting the year, use getFullYear().

Answer (score 8):

An old question, but none of the answers seemed complete, and an update for 2020:

For example: (you may have a decimal if using microsecond precision, e.g. [performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now))

```
let timestamp = 1586438912345.67;
```

And we have:

```
var date = new Date(timestamp); // Thu Apr 09 2020 14:28:32 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
let year = date.getFullYear(); // 2020
let month = date.getMonth() + 1; // 4 (note zero index: Jan = 0, Dec = 11)
let day = date.getDate(); // 9
```

And if you'd like the month and day to always be a two-digit string (e.g. "01"):

```
let month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0'); // "04"
let day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0'); // "09"
```

For extended completeness:

```
let hour = date.getHours(); // 14
let minute = date.getMinutes(); // 28
let second = date.getSeconds(); // 32
let millisecond = date.getMilliseconds(); // 345
let epoch = date.getTime(); // 1586438912345 (Milliseconds since Epoch time)
```

Further, if your timestamp is actually a string to start (maybe from a JSON object, for example):

```
var date = new Date(parseFloat(timestamp));
```

or for right now:

```
var date = new Date(Date.now());
```

More info if you want it [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-date-and-time-in-javascript) (2017).

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using `parse`, which is used to convert a date *string* to a `Date`, just pass it into the `Date` constructor:

```
var date = new Date(timestamp);
```

Make sure your timestamp is a `Number`, of course.