# How to get posting time of post in Blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogs, blogger

is there any way to get the a post's date and time on which it was posted in Blogger using JAVA Script or jQuery?

Comment: need more info, what information are you provided, what format is the information in(JSON,XML,etc), what have you tried

Comment: I'm trying this var timestamp = &quot;<data:post.timestamp/>&quot;; and it just return me post time, but I want time with year

Comment: chek if this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474752/javascript-get-month-year-day-from-unix-timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is just simple, do the following:

1. Go to your [Blog's Settings](http://itgeeksclub.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-fix-undefined-date-in-blogger.html)>>Language and formatting
2. Look at the Timestamp Format, maybe that is set to only the time and does not include days and month.
3. Click the drop-down and change it accordingly (just copy mine above)

Solved! It's just that easy.

[Go to this blog post for details...](http://The%20solution%20is%20just%20simple,%20do%20the%20following:%20%201.%20Go%20to%20your%20[Blog's%20Settings][1]%3E%3ELanguage%20and%20formatting%202.%20Look%20at%20the%20Timestamp%20Format,%20maybe%20that%20is%20set%20to%20only%20the%20time%20and%20does%20not%20include%20days%20and%20month.%203.%20Click%20the%20drop-down%20and%20change%20it%20accordingly%20(just%20copy%20mine%20above)%20%20Solved!%20It's%20just%20that%20easy.%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20http://itgeeksclub.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-fix-undefined-date-in-blogger.html)