# Read timestamp to get Month and Year in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, timestamp

I am new to Angular JS2 and Typescript. I want to read timestamp value and retrieve month and year from it. For example, if the timestamp is "1505726052000", then I need to get the result as "2017, September".

Is there any way to achieve using Angular2 and Typescript? or should I use only JavaScript to solve this?

Comment: This is not an Angular thing, or even Typescript... Just JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474752/javascript-get-month-year-day-from-unix-timestamp

Comment: I thought that, with out calling JS, we can able to achieve. Np! Thanks for your update!